# Is there a fixed-wing aircraft that uses a scissor propeller configuration?

Tags: propeller, fixed-wing

[image]
(Source: [primeportal.net](http://www.primeportal.net/hangar/isaac_gershman/ah-64a/index.php?Page=1))

Has there ever been a fixed-wing aircraft whose propeller is in a scissor configuration? Like the Apache's tail-rotor seen here: [What are the benefits of a non-orthogonal (scissor) tail-rotor?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/43279/14897)

This configuration improves the thrust and reduces the noise. If not, what are the drawbacks for such configuration when used for forward thrust?

The nearest match I could find was a stacked non-counter-rotating propeller. Not being coplanar is the only matching feature. It was on a modified Junkers W 34:

[image]
([Source](http://german767.rssing.com/chan-7262731/all_p4.html))

Comment: Without proof my answer is no. The distance between the wakes of the single propeller blades would be uneven, causing a loss in efficiency. Tractor  aircraft propellers don't have to deal with rotor downwash and a bulky tail structure, and they enjoy the luxury of airflow which is pretty well aligned with their axis of rotation. Helicopter tail rotors suffer a pitiful existence in comparison.

Comment: "*Helicopter tail rotors suffer a pitiful existence in comparison*" I wonder with they don't put the tail rotor above the main rotor to make its life easier.

Comment: @mins is that a joke or a serious question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]
The tandem-engine Rumpler-Loutzkoy-Taube airplane.

---

Above is the closest thing to a scissor propeller I could find. As @PeterKämpf notes, unlike a tail-rotor, a tractor propeller is not in a rotor's downwash and its axis of rotation is aligned with the free stream.

The photo shows the world's first co-axial propeller. And it was **non-contra-rotating,** that is, both propellers rotated in the same direction, like the Apache's.

That, and not being co-planar, are the matching features. Each propeller was powered by a different engine, and they could run at different speeds. Long before variable pitch propellers, it was envisioned (and patented) that the second propeller could have a gearbox to **reverse** its direction for braking (aircraft at the time didn't have brakes).

---

Source: [oldmachinepress.com](https://oldmachinepress.com/2017/05/05/rumpler-loutzkoy-taube-aircraft/)